# oAuth 2.0 Playground

Tags: json, google-fit, oauth2-playground

I am trying to get the steps count using https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

I have Exchange authorization code for tokens and request to API 
GET

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps

in my mobile googleFit APP it's showing the it have been connected to my Project.

The Json response I am getting :

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "dataType": {
    "field": [
      {
        "name": "steps", 
        "format": "integer"
      }
    ], 
    "name": "com.google.step_count.delta"
  }, 
  "application": {
    "packageName": "com.google.android.gms"
  }, 
  "dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps", 
  "type": "derived", 
  "dataStreamName": "estimated_steps"
}
```

but I didn't get the steps count values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link that you can check for integrating google fit to your app

1) [How to get step count from Google Fit REST API like Google Fit app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998823/how-to-get-step-count-from-google-fit-rest-api-like-google-fit-app)

2) https://plus.google.com/+DavidSchmidt/posts/TJjRTefojC6