# Node Js: Not getting the details using dataSources with datasets

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-fit

I tried to get the step count by date wise. When I took the data from google fit using

API:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps/datasets/1457548200000000000-1457631000000000000&token=1111111111

I can get only limited step count but not all the steps on that date. Why this kind of problem's are occurs to get the google fit data.

Can any one suggest me the better way to get all the data from google fit.

Answer (score 0):

Using `derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps` datasource
will give you varying results depending on the scenario. The cause of this is mainly from the sensors used. Maybe this is the reason why you think that you have limited results.

> `estimated_steps` also takes into account activity, and estimates steps
>   when there are none.  For instance, assume the user walked for 30
>   minutes, but the hardware step counter only recorded 10 steps.  We
>   know that number is inaccurate so instead we estimate, say 3000 steps
>   during that time.

This was noted and discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998823/how-to-get-step-count-from-google-fit-rest-api-like-google-fit-app?rq=1).