# Google Fit API - Real Time Data

Tags: api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to show in my application the steps that the user walked per day in real time but I am not able to. I tried to get the steps using `TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE` but I am able to get all the steps from the day that user started using the application.

When I tried to use other type, for example `DELTA`, it's not working. Not sure if I am missing something. I am able to get the daily steps from HISTORY API but I cannot use them for real time because UI does not allow to use `await()`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have already tried

Comment: actually i was using this tutorial for the real time data : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-fit-for-android-reading-sensor-data--cms-25723

Answer (score 0):

The `com.google.step_count.cumulative` data type represents step count data as a sum since the start of the count. So this is not the one that you need.

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_daily_total_data), it is stated here that Google Fit also provides simple access to the daily total of a specified data type. Use the [`HistoryApi.readDailyTotal()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryApi#readDailyTotal(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType)) method to retrieve the data type that you specify as of midnight of the current day in the device's current timezone. For example, pass in the [`TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType#TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA) data type to this method to retrieve the daily total steps. You may pass in an [instantaneous data type](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#data_types_for_instantaneous_readings) that has an aggregate daily total.

But, if you want a real time data, you need to use the `Sensors API` together with the `Recording API`. Source: [Record Fitness Data](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record)

For more information, check this related SO question:

- [Get current day's steps during datapointListener google Fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771616/get-current-days-steps-during-datapointlistener-google-fit)