# Google Fit REST API returns empty point in OAuth Playground. Tried all stack overflow suggestions

Tags: android, rest, api, google-fit

I'm an Android App Developer. I'm getting different values for Steps count each day using Google Fit History API in Android. That's why I want to try with Google Fit REST API itself.

Is getting directly from Google Fit REST Server will give exact result in all device? Will it vary for each device like using Fitness History API? 
I tried in OAuth Playground All I get is empty point.

```
{
  "minStartTimeNs": "1490988661000", 
  "maxEndTimeNs": "1491300438957", 
  "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps", 
  "point": []
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you do it with the GOogle OAuth Playground? Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998823/) if it can help you.

Comment: (https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started)   This is the method I'm following to get steps count via Google OAuth Playground. I'm getting empty value in Point.

Comment: I also gave up after trying all the possible combinations.